# How to setup Esper to use single thread

Tags: esper

I want to use Esper completely in single thread. I have the following config:

```java
config.getEngineDefaults().getExecution().setDisableLocking(true);
config.getEngineDefaults().getThreading().setInternalTimerEnabled(false);
config.getEngineDefaults().getThreading().setThreadPoolInbound(false);
config.getEngineDefaults().getThreading().setThreadPoolOutbound(false);
config.getEngineDefaults().getThreading().setThreadPoolRouteExec(false);
epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), config);
```

I push events using:

```
epService.getEPRuntime().route(myEvent);
```

I have one statement, and I added one listener using `EPStatement.addListener(UpdateListener)`. However, the `update` method of the listener is never called. I also send timer events:

```
epService.getEPRuntime().route(new CurrentTimeEvent(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

As I understand from the documentation, the `route()` method is supposed to directly call listeners, but my `update()` method is never called.

Answer (score 0):

The method to send events into Esper is "sendEvent". The "route" method is for use by listener code and listener code can send events in for processing using "route".